# Add VisualizePanel from Weka to SWT modal

Tags: java, swt, weka

I am trying to add a VisualizePanel from Weka to a created shell to add a plot of data to it. I have tried `shell.setLayoutData(VisualizePanel)` but once run it doesn't load the VisualizePanel and only loads the shell itself. Is there a way to do this?

```
Shell visual_shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX | SWT.ON_TOP);
            visual_shell.pack();

visual_shell.setSize(800,600);
visual_shell.open();

final VisualizePanel panel = new VisualizePanel();
visual_shell.setLayoutData(panel);
PlotData2D p2d = new PlotData2D(data);  
panel.setMasterPlot(p2d);

while (!visual_shell.isDisposed()) {
     if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
          display.sleep();
     }
}
```

Comment: That appears to use Swing/AWT - you can't use Swing components directly in SWT, you must use the SWT_AWT bridge - see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html)

Comment: Also note that your use of `setLayoutData` is completely wrong. layout data is used for specifying how existing controls are arranged on the shell, not for adding controls. See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm)